# Sticky element begin in the direct centre of the page?

Tags: jquery, center, sticky

I've created a website that displays the logo in the direct centre of the page. At the moment, the div's position is fixed. The logo also include an image map. What I'd like is for it to be absolute and when the user scrolls down, the logo will reach about 20px from the top and will become fixed. Very similar to Waypoints.

So although I can organise Waypoints, I can't get the site to load with the logo in the direct centre of the page (regardless the screen size). Any help would be greatly appreciated!\

My HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
<img src="images/logo.png" />
</div>
```

My Css:

```
.logo {
   width: 351px;
   height: 185px;
   position: fixed;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -175px;
   margin-top: -92px;
   text-align:center;
   overflow:hidden;
   z-index: 900;
}
```

Comment: Seeing the code you've tried would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the dimensions of the window height. Add this to your JS and then you can use it in the format of `$('.logo').centerScreen`.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery.fn.centerScreen = function(loaded) { 
                var obj = this; 
                if(!loaded) { 
                        obj.css('top', $(window).height()/2- 
                                this.height()/2); 
                        obj.css('left', $(window).width()/2- 
                                this.width()/2); 
                        $(window).resize(function() 
                                { obj.centerScreen(!loaded); }); 
                } else { 
                        obj.stop(); 
                        obj.animate({ top: $(window).height()/2- 
                                this.height()/2, left: $ 
                                (window).width()/2-this.width()/2}, 200, 'linear'); 
                } 
        } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks good but i'm unsure how to implement that into the HTML side of things.